How to approach exercise I.6.4 from Elstrodt: Maß- und Integrationstheorie
I’m working through exercise 6.4 in chapter 1 from the book on Measure Theory by Elstrodt and need some help with proving a result. Here’s the problem:

Let $\mathfrak{E}$ be a generator of the algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ over the set $X$ and $\mathfrak{E} \subset \mathfrak{D} \subset \mathfrak{A}$. The system $\mathfrak{E}$ is stable under the intersection of two sets and $\mathfrak{D}$ satisfies the following properties:
(i) $X \in \mathfrak{D}$,
(ii) If $A \in \mathfrak{D}$, then $A^c \in \mathfrak{D}$,
(iii) If $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in \mathfrak{D}$ are disjoint, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in \mathfrak{D}$.
Show that $\mathfrak{D} = \mathfrak{A}$.

The exercise also remarks that this is a finitely additive version of Proposition 6.7 proven in the book.

Proposition 6.7: If $\mathfrak{E} \subset \mathfrak{P}(X)$ is the stable under the intersection of two sets, then the Dynkin-system generated by $\mathfrak{E}$ is equal to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathfrak{E}$.
Proof: By Proposition 6.6, we only need to show that the Dynkin-system generated by $\mathfrak{E}$ is stable under the intersection of two sets. To prove this we define the set of "good sets" for a set $D \in \mathfrak{D}$ as$$
\mathfrak{O}(D) := \{ M \subset X: M \cap D \in \mathfrak{D} \}.
$$
Then $\mathfrak{O}(D)$ is a Dynkin-system since $M^c \cap D = D \setminus (M \cap D) \in \mathfrak{D}$ (Proposition 6.5). For every $E \in \mathfrak{E}$, $\mathfrak{E} \subset \mathfrak{O}(E)$ since $\mathfrak{E}$ is stable under the intersection of two sets. Thus, $\mathfrak{D} \subset \mathfrak{O}(E)$ ($E \in \mathfrak{E}$).
Now let $E \in \mathfrak{E}$, $D \in \mathfrak{D}$. Then $D \in \mathfrak{O}(E)$, and therefore $E \in \mathfrak{O}(D)$ (Definiton of $\mathfrak{D}$!). It follows that $E \in \mathfrak{O}(D)$, hence $\mathfrak{D} \subset \mathfrak{O}(D)$. Thus, $\mathfrak{D}$ is stable under the intersection of two sets as claimed.


Proposition 6.5: A system of subsets $\mathfrak{D} \subset \mathfrak{P}(X)$ is a Dynkin-system if and only if:
a) $X \in \mathfrak{D}$.
b) For all $A,B \in \mathfrak{D}$ such that $B \subset A$, $A \setminus B \in \mathfrak{D}$.
c) $\mathfrak{D}$ is a monotone class.


Proposition 6.6: A Dynkin-system is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is closed under the intersection of two sets.

I am omitting the proofs of Proposition 6.5 and Proposition 6.6 for brevity as they are quite basic.
Now my idea to prove the exercise was to show that $\mathfrak{D}$ is an algebra to prove that $\mathfrak{D} \subset \mathfrak{A}$. I could try to follow a similar strategy as in the proof of Proposition 6.6, but in the exercise $\mathfrak{D}$ is not generated by $\mathfrak{E}$.
We need to somehow make use of property (iii) I think. For example if $A, B \in \mathfrak{D}$, then we could write $A \cup B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$, but we do not know whether $B \setminus A \in \mathfrak{D}$. I run into a similar problem when considering $A \cap B$.
A hint would be much appreciated. Am I even on the right track or should I approach the problem in a different way?
Thanks a lot!

$\def\C{\mathscr{C}}\def\D{\mathscr{D}}\def\S{\mathscr{S}}\def\emptyset{\varnothing}$Definition 1: For a set $X$ and $\D \subseteq 2^X$, if:

$X \in \D$;
$A^c \in \D$ for any $A \in \D$;
$A \cup B \in \D$ for any disjoint $A, B \in \D$,

then $\D$ is a disjoint algebra over $X$.
Definition 2: For a set $X$ and $\S \subseteq 2^X$, the intersection of all disjoint algebras over $X$ that contains $\S$ is the disjoint algebra generated by $\S$, denoted by $d(\S)$.
Note: The algebra generated by $\S$ is denoted by $a(\S)$.
Now the proposition to be proved is:

Proposition: If $\C$ is a π-system over $X$, $\D$ is a disjoint algebra over $X$, and $\C \subseteq \D \subseteq a(\C)$, then $\D = a(\C)$.

The key part here is to prove $d(\C)$ is a π-system, which enables the use of the minimality of $d(\C)$, and effectively replaces $\D$ in the proposition with $d(\C)$.
(Stop here if you want a hint only. Below is the full solution.)

Denote for $D \in d(\C)$,$$
\S(D) = \{A \subseteq X \mid A \cap D \in d(\C)\}.
$$

Proposition 1: For any $D \in d(\C)$, $\S(D)$ is a disjoint algebra over $X$.

Proof: First, $X \cap D = D \in d(\C)$ implies $X \in \S(D)$.
For any $A \in \S(D)$, since $A \cap D, D^c \in d(\C)$ and $(A \cap D) \cap D^c = \emptyset$, then$$
A \cup D^c = (A \cap D) \cup D^c \in d(\C),\quad A^c \cap D = {(A \cup D^c)}^c \in d(\C),
$$
thus $A^c \in \S(D)$.
For any disjoint $A, B \in \S(D)$, since$$
A \cap D, B \cap D \in d(\C),\quad (A \cap D) \cap (B \cap D) = (A \cap B) \cap D = \emptyset,
$$
then$$
(A \cup B) \cap D = (A \cap D) \cup (B \cap D) \in d(\C),
$$
thus $A \cup B \in \S(D)$.

Proposition 2: $d(\C) \subseteq \S(C)$ for any $C \in \C$.

Proof: For any $C_1 \in \C$, since $\C$ is a π-system, then $C_1 \cap C \in \C \subseteq d(\C)$, so $C_1 \in \S(C)$. Hence $\C \subseteq \S(C)$, and Proposition 1 implies that $d(\C) \subseteq \S(C)$.

Proposition 3: $d(\C) \subseteq \S(D)$ for any $D \in d(\C)$.

Proof: For any $C \in \C$, Proposition 2 implies that $D \in \S(C)$, i.e. $C \cap D \in d(\C)$, or $C \in \S(D)$. Hence $\C \subseteq \S(D)$, and analogously $d(\C) \subseteq \S(D)$.

Proposition 3 shows that $d(\C)$ is a π-system, hence an algebra. Therefore,$$
a(\C) \subseteq d(\C) \subseteq d(\D) = \D \subseteq a(\C),
$$
and $\D = a(\C)$.
